# Comparing locally maximal and localy minimal Hamiltonian paths

Tags: correctness-proof, hamiltonian-path

Let $K_n$ be a weighted complete graph on $n$ vertices. Two Hamiltonian paths are
formed as follows. The first one, $H$, is formed by starting at an arbitrary vertex, and at each stage proceeding from the current location to the unvisited vertex maximizing the weight of the connecting edge. The second one, $h$, is formed similarly, except that at each stage one chooses the unvisited vertex minimizing the weight of the connecting edge. Prove that $w(H) \ge w(h)$.

I tried with induction. For $k=3$, the conclusion is fulfilled. We assume that $w(H)\ge w(h)$ for a Hamiltonian path with size $n-1$ and try to prove it for a Hamiltonian path with size $n$, where I got stuck. How can I go ahead with induction?

Comment: What did you try and where did you get stuck?

Comment: I am stuck with a formal proof of this.

Comment: OK. How did you start the proof attempt?

Comment: @arielb Basically, you're just saying "Here's my homework. I can't do it. Please help me." Without knowing what you're stuck with, the only way we can help is to give you a full solution, but we're not going to do that -- it's your homework, not ours.

Comment: I tried with induction, for k=3 , the condition is fulfilled. We assume that w(H)>=w(h) for a Hamiltonian path with size n-1 and try to prove it for a Hamiltonian path with size n.

Comment: @arielb, it is expected of you to **raise a question** in your post. Since you are stuck in the induction step apparently, I just did it for you this time since you are a newcomer.